# Recursive chmod file and dirs on debian behaves differently to CentOS

Tags: find

Both of these commands run ok on `Debian` but do not work on `CentOS`:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
```

any idea to solve?

Comment: You need to escape the semi colon (`;`): `\;`.

Comment: @geedoubleya but that would be true no matter which distribution was in use!

Comment: @Celada - that is why it is a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like geedoubleya said, you are missing a '\' at the end of your find commands. So change these:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
```

To these:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

You need to escape the semicolon because "find" and its subshell created with -exec interpret that character, so it must be escaped. You can also use single quotes on the semicolon instead. For example ';' instead of \;

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ';'
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ';'
```

Comment: Can we explain why we need this backslash in the answer?

Comment: Sorry I meant can we edit the answer to include this?

Comment: I updated my answer.